# AWS Cloud Formation templates configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to copie the content for bucket S3 source to Bucket S3 destinitation with using only cloudformation Remember the cloudformation forma.yaml

Comment: Not possible without custom resources.

Comment: What is the meaning of custom resources? I have already created a Lambda function with resources like SQS and S3 in the template, but I want to copy the data from external buckets to these buckets in the template

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in CloudFormation to do the copying. This will be in the form of a lambda function which will perform the copying action which you have to write.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to fix this? I already saw this; it can't help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-transfer-workflow-copystepdetails.html